# Excel VBA Loop Cell Link on Form Combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I'm needing a Function that can change the cell link on form control Combo Boxes that already exist on an active sheet using a loop. I can currently achieve this with out a loop as follows

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Combobox 1").OLEFormat.Object.LinkedCell = Worksheets("Test").Cells(2, 2).Address
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Combobox 2").OLEFormat.Object.LinkedCell = Worksheets("Test").Cells(2, 3).Address
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Combobox 3").OLEFormat.Object.LinkedCell = Worksheets("Test").Cells(2, 4).Address
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Combobox 4").OLEFormat.Object.LinkedCell = Worksheets("Test").Cells(2, 5).Address
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Combobox 5").OLEFormat.Object.LinkedCell = Worksheets("Test").Cells(2, 6).Address
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Combobox 6").OLEFormat.Object.LinkedCell = Worksheets("Test").Cells(2, 7).Address
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Combobox 7").OLEFormat.Object.LinkedCell = Worksheets("Test").Cells(2, 8).Address
```

So I want to use a loop rather than having to do this for every combobox on my sheet, the loop needs to increment the .Cell row number and .Shape("Combobox 1"). I'm stuck in writing the loop because the combo box is using a name or string value and not an int value.

Any help on this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this format:

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, i As Long, os As Long

Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Test")

os = 1     'change i Offset as needed

For i = 1 To 7
    ws1.Shapes("Combobox " & i).OLEFormat.Object.LinkedCell = ws2.Cells(2, i + os).Address
Next
```

Comment: This works fine, only issue is comboboxs 1 to 7 I might need to link to rows 8-14 as an example is it possible to have the combobox and .Cell row number as independent variables rather than the same variable?

Comment: See edited answer: I added a new variable "os" (off set) so you can easily update it as needed. Cell row number cannot be entirely independent from comboboxes: if you have 7 checkboxes you must update 7 rows. The only independed aspect is that rows can have a dynamic position, offset from row 1

Comment: The code supplied will only give the range address, `$B$2` not `Test!$B$2`. Possibly you would require,`ws2.Name & "!" & ws2.Cells(2, i + os).Address`.   The OP asked about rows, your edited code only changes the columns

Comment: @Davesexcel: correct - the OP question asks to increment .Cell *row number*, but the OP code updates the columns (I used the OP code for the answer)

Comment: I assume if the OP didn't notice the linked cell issue, the `activesheet` and `Worksheets("Test")` are the same sheet.

Comment: @Davesexcel: Thanks for that I've just been messing with it today and noticed it change the cell link to the active sheet.